# How to setup a wordpress edit page in admin area

Tags: wordpress, plugins, admin

Developing a wordpress plugin I have problems to setup a custom edit page to handle my items in the admin area. I have been taking a look what is the workflow in case of posts and as I see all edit actions are redirected from edit.php to `post.php?post=33&action=edit`. I have been setting up an option page and I handle from here all items edits but in this case shows the menu in the sidebar what is not optimal for the user, because if no item id is passed to it can cause a lot problems. I have to mention, developing Wordpress plugins is something new for me and maybe the researches what I made are not proper. I have been taking a look in wordpress API and  I found the following function

```
add_management_page().
```

but this needs to be ordered under the admin menu

adding the following function and linking my items edit like

```
admin.php?page=parser-target-edit&record=73

add_submenu_page( 'parser-top-level-handle', 'Edit', 'Sub-menu title', 'manage_options', 'parser-target-edit', array($this , 'edit_item') );
```

is working but as I said is showing up in the sidebar as menu item. So it has to be another workaround what it can be used in case of edit action

Answer (score 1):

You can try [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) which can be coupled to [add_submenu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) to create administration pages

You can execute a callback function that gets executed from [add_menu_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page).